# How to remove focus from UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have seen this question asked million times everywhere, but there's no single answer that has been working for me.

I need to remove focus from a UITextField. That means I need the cursor to go away (and the keyboard dismissed).

The solution I've seen on the internet is either `[textfield resignFirstResponder]` or `[textfield endEditing:YES]`, which is able to hide the keyboard, but does not remove focus from UITextField (i.e. the cursor still blinking happily inside the UITextField, although the keyboard is dismissed).

The thing with this is I need to get event when the user tap into the UITextField and the event didBeginEditing is fired. I'm doing something each time that event is fired, or more generally, each time the user tap on the UITextField. But if the focus isn't removed entirely from the UITextField, the event can't be fired again even after I called `resignFirstResponder` or `endEditing:YES`.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: try make something else become the first responder, maybe just the base view of the viewcontroller

Comment: your keyboard is resigned and only cursor is available

Comment: @Fonix I've already tried to set textfield.superView to firstresponder, but it doesn't help. Another guide tells that I need to set firstresponder to another textfield. But I don't have any other textfield. I only have that one textfield in the screen, with other components, but no other components can become firstresponder besides the textfield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem ages ago.

I had a screen containing a `UITextField`, and some other controls, some of which were appearing *under* the onscreen keyboard  (yes, I know now I should've used constraints to make sure the onscreen `UIView` fitted the visible part of the screen).

The problem in my case was that on a Modal screen, once the onscreen keyboard appears, you can *never* get rid of it, even if you try using `resignFirstResponder`.  In its wisdom, Apple has deliberately designed it this way, to stop the user being annoyed by the keyboard appearing, and disappearing.  Uh-huh.

My solution was simple:

Make your `UITextField` *disabled*.  Even if it's just for a fraction of a second, then you re-enable it.

This'll make the onscreen keyboard nicely slide away.

Answer (score 5):

you can make the cusor color as clear color

```
  textfeild.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

if you just want to dismiss the keyboard then

```
    textfeild.resignFirstResponder()
```

will dismiss the keyboard and when you want focus again use

```
 textfeild.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: It doesn't help because I don't want to just dismiss the keyboard. I want the textfield to also remove focus. Setting the cursor to clearcolor also doesn't help because the cursor still in there. If the textfield is still in focus, then becomeFirstResponder also won't fire the didBeginEditing event. I need the didBeginEditing event to be fired when the user tap on the textfield, but the event can't be fired the second time if I can't make the textfield lose focus.

Comment: -(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
} try this i my case cusor is not appearing and also set delegate to self

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to detect when the textfield is touched and not specifically the `didBeginEditing`, why not just make a subclass of UITextField and override `touchesBegan` like so

```
class SpecialTextField: UITextField {
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touched textfield")
    }
}
```

then you can use that to fire your event via a delegate method, or directly somehow

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still facing the issue, the cursor remains if resignFirstResponder() is not called from main queue.

So you just need to:

```html
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  textView.resignFirstResponder()
}
```